# UpdateController gives error about PartialTypeDTO conflicting with Interface used in Service

Tags: typescript, interface, controller, nestjs, dto

CreateAdmin.DTO.ts
[image]

UpdateAdmin.DTO.ts

Which is inherited by PartialTypes so the values whilst updating the admin are optional for all fields.

[image]

AdminInterface.ts

[image]

admin.controller.ts

This is my update controller, I want to use the PartialTypes without having to create a second interface for this(I don't know why, That seems wrong to use 2 interfaces).

[image]

This is the error that is being displayed on VSCODE.

[image]

I tried making a second interface but that seemed wrong as mentioned earlier.

So the solution right now, What I can see is to make a new interface for the Update(Patch/PUT) endpoints.

Admin.Service.ts
[image]

Comment: Please show the code for your `adminService.updateAdmin` method

Comment: Suggestion: include code formatted instead of screenshots (check the Stack Overflow formatting help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Typescript error is clear. All of your `UpdateAdminDTO` properties are marked as optional, whilst your `Admin` interface expected in the `updateAdmin` method for your `AdminService` does not allow optional properties.

If you're leaned towards a more DDD-ish design, you will have to map your `UpdateAdminDTO` data to your `Admin` interface.

Comment: I made another interface for updating Admin which resolved the issue as mentioned above.